# vba DoCmd.OpenForm where condition error 3075

Tags: forms, vba

Trying to open a form to a specific record. the code is

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAssistHeader", , , "[PartNumber] =" & Me.[Part Number], , , PN
```

i get the the following

> Run-Time error '3075'
>
> syntax error in number in query expression '[PartNumber]=196.173.15'.

note that the 196.176.15 should be 196.173.157 my layout is as follows

[PartNumber] is on frmAssistHeader

[Part Number] is on frmMenu

Both are text and need to stay as text.

Comment: Looks like you will need to put quotations around the part number value.

Comment: the [Part number] or the [partNumber]

Comment: [Part Number]. So something like "[PartNumber] =""" & Me.[Part Number] & """". I can't double check the exact syntax where I'm at but since PartNumber is expecting a string, the value on the right side of the equal sign has to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: that gets rid of the error but it opens a new record.